# MySQL, repeat all values for each value from the first column

Tags: mysql

Sorry, I don't even know how to ask, but that's the thing. I have one small table with 30 rows.

I want to select all values from one column and with each value bring all the values from another column, repeating.

Let me try to show, small example, this is my table and values:

```
[column color] / [column qtd]
blue / 3
red / 5
gray / 7
yellow / 2
```

I want to bring that result on a SELECT query:

```
blue / 3
blue / 5
blue / 7
blue / 2
red / 3
red / 5
red / 7
red / 2
gray / 3
gray / 5
gray / 7
gray / 2
yellow / 3
yellow / 5
yellow / 7
yellow / 2
```

It's bring all the values from column color and bring all the values from qtd repeating for each different color value.

Sorry, it's kinda hard to explain :(

But thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may perform a `CROSS JOIN` against a subquery returning the `DISTINCT qtd` from the same table. That will result in all rows from the subquery joined to all rows of `DISTINCT color`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  color,
  q.qtd
FROM
  /* Assuming your table is `color` */
  color
  /* CROSS JOIN (like an inner join with no ON clause) */
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT qtd FROM color
  ) q
ORDER BY color, q.qtd
```

Here is a demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42342/3

Comment: that's perfect, thank you very much. Cross Join, another thing to learn. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want all the combinations of the two values in your table.  Use a `cross join` with `distinct`:

```
select c.color, q.qtd
from (select distinct color from table t) c cross join
     (select distinct qtd from table t) q
```